# Not able to read json data in $_POST when sent using angularjs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, angularjs

In angular I have :

```
var data = {};
data['name'] = "test";
data['class'] = "testClass";

$http.post('http://testURL',data,function(data){
console.log(data);
});
```

When in the PHP code I do : `var_dump($_POST)`, i get an empty array.And thus I have to access the data using `file_get_contents("php://input");` (the raw data stream).

QUESTION: Why do i have to use the raw data stream ? If I send the data using normal ajax call in jQuery I am able to get the data in $_POST but in angularjs this is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

When you are posting json data, the content type will by application/json. The $_POST array in PHP is only used when the post data is www-form-urlencoded, which application/json is not. That's why you need to read from php://input.

But most popular php frameworks handle this with a more readable API like this in controller context:

```
<?php
class Controller {
    function action($request) {
        $data = $request->json();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because AngularJS send the data as `application/json` by default, and there's nothing wrong with that. jQuery convert it to `x-www-form-urlencoded` on sending the data.

If you want to get it as jQuery way, you may need to add some config on your `http` provider.

There's still jQuery contribution on my app, this is my `http` config :

```
angular.module('app')
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data){ if (data) return jQuery.param(data); };

}]);
```